# Django 1.10 migration support for apps in subdirectories

Tags: django

I put a simple project together with two apps in an `apps` directory:

```
myproject/
| manage.py
|-- myproject/
|   | __init__.py
|   | settings.py
|   | urls.py
|   | wsgi.py
|-- apps/
|   | __init__.py
|   | app1/ # with models.py and views.py
|   | app2/ # with models.py and views.py
```

I've updated the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting to include `apps.app1` and `apps.app2`.

The `apps.app1` is the only app with models:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    stuff = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

If I run `./manage.py check` and it comes back fine.

However, if I try to run `./manage.py makemigrations apps.app1` I get the following error:

```
App 'apps.app1' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?
```

But `apps.app1` is clearly in the settings file, here is the settings file (copy and pasted):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.app1',
    'apps.app2',
]
```

Other things I've read seem to indicate that is should be possible to have Django apps in subdirectories.

**Is this not actually possible? OR, if it is possible, what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run [`makemigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#makemigrations) you should use the app [`label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label) (e.g. `app1`), not the [`name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name) (e.g. `apps.app1`).

```
./manage.py makemigrations app1
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a simple solution to something I've been struggling with for two days.